# Angularjs Ng-init shows the same retrieved form values when passed through ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Am having an issues with angularjs ng-init(). In my table called post, I have 3 rows inserted. For example

```
insert into post(id,title)values(1,'title1');
insert into post(id,title)values(2,'title2');
insert into post(id,title)values(3,'title3');
```

Now I have retrieved the records and pass it through ng-repeat and everything works fine.

My problem is the **ng-init()** function. when I passed the database values into a form inputs with **ng-init** initialized within the **ng-repeat**, its shows the last database values all through in the form inputs **(Eg. 3, title3)**

```
<input type='text' ng-model='title' ng-model='$parent.title' ng-init="$parent.title=post.title" >
```

if I add value attribute to the form (Eg. `value={{post.id}})` it will show the correct form values on each row but when I click on submit button, the value attribute will not be submitted but it will rather pass the value to ng-init which keeps submitting only the last database records **(Eg. 3, title3)** irrespective of the form button on each row that was clicked.

I have attached the screenshot that shows how the ng-init displays only the last record in a form values instead of showing all records corresponding to each form rows

[image]

but I was expecting to have is the form below or a work around within the angularjs controller or equivalents

[image]

below is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body ng-app='myapp'>
  <div class="content" ng-controller='fetchCtrl'>
    <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>

<form bind-to-scope='$parent' >

                    post Id<br>
                    <input type='text' ng-model='pid' ng-model='$parent.pid' ng-init="$parent.pid=post.id" >
                <br>

post Title<br>
                    <input type='text' ng-model='title' ng-model='$parent.title' ng-init="$parent.title=post.title" >
                <br>


                   <input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save' ng-click="submitButton()" >
</form>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Script -->
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>




 <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

        fetch.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {


            // Add new record
            $scope.submitButton = function(){

var pid=$scope.pid;

//alert variables values that is all I want
alert(pid);


// do http thing here if you like

             $http({   

            });


            }
// Fetch post data scope goes here

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why u have taken `$parent?` you can directly bind `post.id`

Comment: @Sravan, without $parent, it will display those form values as undefined when you try to submit the form.

Comment: you can take a scope object variable instead

Comment: @chinazaike why you need `ng-init` in first place? you could directly use `ng-model="post.id"` and `ng-model="post.title"` directly. I guess, I don't understand whole usecase. would you mind explaining the same?

Comment: @Pankaj if use for instance ng-modl="post.title". how do I  now pass it as form variable. for example I have tried var pid=$scope.post.pid; or var pid=$scope.pid; alert(pid); but it does not work anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few issues in your code: **Here are few issues in your question**

- `$parent` is not required to bind the data
- You have taken ng-model twice in each input which is wrong
- Also, ng-model binds the data automatically, ng-init is not required.

**Here is the solution:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <form>
    post Id<br>
    <input type='text' ng-model='post.pid' >
    <br> post Title<br>
    <input type='text' ng-model='post.title'>
    <br>
    <input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save' ng-click="submitButton()">
</form>
</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.posts = [
    {
      "pid" : "1",
      "title" : "title1"
    },
    {
      "pid" : "2",
      "title" : "title2"
    },
    {
      "pid" : "3",
      "title" : "title3"
    },
  ]
  
  $scope.submitButton = function(){
    alert(angular.toJson($scope.posts))
  }
  
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/C1HwC2UOjgOwp3fEnZFL?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I can no longer pass ng-model values as form variables so that I can submit each data. I have tried for example  var pid=$scope.post.pid; or  var pid=$scope.pid;  alert(pid); but it does not work anymore

Comment: means? can you emplaim more?